# How to calculate number of days between two given dates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two datetime objects  `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`

```
d1 = 2022-04-25 08:27:36
d2 = 2022-01-28 20:41:57
```

What is the best way to get the number of days between these two dates in python?

Comment: `(d1 - d2).days`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this function(if you're using YY-MM-DD):

```
def numOfDays(date1, date2):
    return (date2-date1).days
```